# With two houses and two internet connections, I want to use site A's internet from site B via a VPN, preferably wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, internet, nat, wireguard

I have two homes, both of which have internet. Let's say that I am currently at "Site A", but I want to connect to the internet via "Site B", in order to take advantage of Site B's preferable geolocation.

Naively, I would set up a wireguard server at Site B, and then connect to to it from Site A, but the situation is complicated by the fact that Site B is behind NAT which I cannot disable.

Is there a way to operate a wireguard server from behind NAT? My initial thought was to put a third server in the cloud, "Site C", have Site B connect out to Site C, and also connect out to Site C from Site A. But I have no idea how to configure wireguard to cope with this configuration, or if it is even possible.

Any tips?

Comment: You don't your house for geolocation, just use a VPN service,

Comment: Thanks harrymc, but I cannot do that, because I need to be connecting from a residential IP block.

Comment: "NAT which I cannot disable" is an odd phrase. Do you mean CG-NAT? i.e. is your public IP address in the 100.64.0.0-100.127.255.255 range? Otherwise, the vast majority of domestic connections would involve NAT, and yes, you can host behind the NAT on your (NAT) router, since you can configure port forwarding on your (NAT) router.

Comment: alternatively, there are solutions (many even use wireguard under the hood) that use NAT traversal so that the two endpoints connect directly to each other rather than via a middle server ... Tailscale, Netbird, Nebula, Netmaker etc

Comment: One can connect to a VPN from everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem.

I set up a server in the cloud with two wireguard interfaces, and had each home location connect *out* to the cloud instance.

I then used IP routing and iptables' NAT to forward traffic from one to the other.

It does mean I have to maintain a cloud VPS, but it works great.